# EWS managed API AutoDiscover is running very slow

Tags: exchangewebservices, ews-managed-api

I'm using EWS API for consuming outlook 365 mail service.

When I'm performing any mail operation it's running slow.

I have written the code mentioned below:

```
ExchangeService service = new    ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2013_SP1);
service.Credentials = new WebCredentials("usernm", "pwd");  
service.EnableScpLookup = false;  
service.AutodiscoverUrl("user",RedirectionUrlValidationCallback);
```

That last line takes 16 seconds before the connection is successful.
Is there any way to make the performance faster?

Comment: Gopal, I have added all your comment answers into your question, Please do that yourself next time. And is *When I'm performing any mail operation it's running slow.* still true ('any'?). [edit] your question.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say...**not saying this is the answer**

but try this and let me know.

I see a difference in that i dont pass RedirectionUrlValidationCallback in the autoDiscoverUrl and I don't set EnableScpLookup flag,  dont know what that is for. **let me know**

```
public ExchangeService GetService( string autoDiscoverEmailAddress, string authEmailAddress,string authEmailPassword, string domain = null, ExchangeVersion verion = ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP2 )
        {
            try 
            {
                ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = CertificateValidationCallBack;

                ExchangeService svc = new ExchangeService(verion);

                //svc.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(domain))
                {
                    svc.Credentials = new WebCredentials(authEmailAddress, authEmailPassword, domain);
                }
                else
                {
                    svc.Credentials = new WebCredentials(authEmailAddress, authEmailPassword);
                }
                svc.AutodiscoverUrl(autoDiscoverEmailAddress);


                return svc;
            }
            catch (Exception) 
            {
                throw;
            }

        }
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but the AutodiscoverUrl is throwing an error like  Autodiscover blocked a potentially insecure redirection to https://autodiscover-s.outlook.com/autodiscover/autodiscover.xml. To allow Autodiscover to follow the redirection, use the AutodiscoverUrl(string, AutodiscoverRedirectionUrlValidationCallback) overload.

Comment: About EnableScpLookup flag, I took a suggestion from the following link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn659837%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx